# R nested lists indexing with another list

Tags: r, string, list, lapply, nested-lists

I am facing some nested list blues in R.

I have two nested lists like the ones shown below, except that each is of size 200 million. I am interested in indexing aaa with bIdx i.e. pluck out the corresponding entries from aaa based on the index specified in bIdx. For example, after the operation we would pluck 1,8,10 entries from aaa[[6]] i.e. "TopNews", "Opinion" and "Opinion".

Since the lists are huge, solutions based on iterating over the lists are not an option and I want a lapply (or variants) based solution.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
aaa
[[1]]
character(0)

[[2]]
character(0)

[[3]]
character(0)

[[4]]
[1] "TopNews" "TopNews"

[[5]]
[1] "Opinion"

[[6]]
 [1] "TopNews" "TopNews" "TopNews" "Opinion" "TopNews" "TopNews" "Opinion"
 [8] "Opinion" "Opinion" "Opinion" "Opinion" "Opinion"

[[7]]
 [1] "N.Y./Region" "Opinion"     "Opinion"     "Opinion"     "Opinion"    
 [6] "Opinion"     "TopNews"     "TopNews"     "TopNews"     "Opinion"    

[[8]]
[1] "TopNews" "TopNews" "TopNews"

[[9]]
[1] "Opinion" "Opinion" "TopNews" "Opinion" "TopNews"

[[10]]
[1] "TopNews" "Opinion" "TopNews" "TopNews" "Opinion"




bIdx
[[1]]
integer(0)

[[2]]
integer(0)

[[3]]
integer(0)

[[4]]
[1] 1 2

[[5]]
[1] 1

[[6]]
[1]  1  8 10

[[7]]
[1] 3 8

[[8]]
[1] 2

[[9]]
[1] 3

[[10]]
[1] 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic case for `mapply`. This function takes a function as first argument (in this case the indexing function `[`). It then loops over the lists in the following arguments and uses the selected elements as the 1st, 2nd, ... argument to the function specified.

An example:

```
aaa <- list(
  character(0),
  letters[1:4],
  letters[10:20]
)

bldx <- list(
  integer(0),
  c(2,1),
  c(7,3,2)
)

mapply(`[`,aaa,bldx)
```

On a sidenote: your lists aren't really nested. A nested list would be a list with its elements being lists again (see eg. the output of `lm`).

Comment: Thanks! I knew I was missing something obvious! :) If not nested, then what  would you call this kind of lists?

Comment: I call this type of list... list. Lists of vectors if I need to be irritatingly pedantic ;-)